# yum not working in Cent-OS

Tags: yum, centos-7

I install fresh Cent-OS 7  but when i want to update or get new packages i get 
this error:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
 One of the configured repositories failed (Unknown),
 and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
 safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:
 1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

 2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
    upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
    distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
    packages for the previous distribution release still work).

 3. Disable the repository, so yum won't use it by default. Yum will then
    just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it again or use
    --enablerepo for temporary usage:

        yum-config-manager --disable <repoid>

 4. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
    Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
    so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
    slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
    compromise:

        yum-config-manager --save --setopt=<repoid>.skip_if_unavailable=true

Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: base/7/x86_64`
```

and this is `yum repolist all`:

```
repo id                                                              repo name                                                              status
C7.0.1406-base/x86_64                                                CentOS-7.0.1406 - Base                                                 disabled
C7.0.1406-centosplus/x86_64                                          CentOS-7.0.1406 - CentOSPlus                                           disabled
C7.0.1406-extras/x86_64                                              CentOS-7.0.1406 - Extras                                               disabled
C7.0.1406-fasttrack/x86_64                                           CentOS-7.0.1406 - CentOSPlus                                           disabled
C7.0.1406-updates/x86_64                                             CentOS-7.0.1406 - Updates                                              disabled
base/7/x86_64                                                        CentOS-7 - Base                                                        enabled: 0
base-debuginfo/x86_64                                                CentOS-7 - Debuginfo                                                   disabled
base-source/7                                                        CentOS-7 - Base Sources                                                disabled
centosplus/7/x86_64                                                  CentOS-7 - Plus                                                        disabled
centosplus-source/7                                                  CentOS-7 - Plus Sources                                                disabled
cr/7/x86_64                                                          CentOS-7 - cr                                                          disabled
extras/7/x86_64                                                      CentOS-7 - Extras                                                      enabled: 0
extras-source/7                                                      CentOS-7 - Extras Sources                                              disabled
fasttrack/7/x86_64                                                   CentOS-7 - fasttrack                                                   disabled
updates/7/x86_64                                                     CentOS-7 - Updates                                                     enabled: 0
updates-source/7                                                     CentOS-7 - Updates Sources                                             disabled
repolist: 0
```

and content of `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo`:

```
# CentOS-Base.repo
#
# The mirror system uses the connecting IP address of the client and the
# update status of each mirror to pick mirrors that are updated to and
# geographically close to the client.  You should use this for CentOS updates
# unless you are manually picking other mirrors.
#
# If the mirrorlist= does not work for you, as a fall back you can try the 
# remarked out baseurl= line instead.
#
#

[base]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Base
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=os&infra=$infra
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/os/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7

#released updates 
[updates]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Updates
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=updates&infra=$infra
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/updates/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7

#additional packages that may be useful
[extras]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Extras
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=extras&infra=$infra
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/extras/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7

#additional packages that extend functionality of existing packages
[centosplus]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Plus
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=centosplus&infra=$infra
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/centosplus/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
```

after Uncomment the `baseurl` in the `CentOS-Base.repo` I got this error 
again but with different in the last :

```
failure: repodata/repomd.xml from base: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#6 - "Could not resolve host: mirror.centos.org; Unknown error"
```

Comment: Could you include your current configuration for the `base/7/x86_64` repo?

Comment: your mean is `/etc/yum.repos.d/` folder?? @nkn

Comment: may give me the full path? @nkn

Comment: Yes, you probably have there several `base` definitions as per your output. Include the one that references `base/7/x86_64`.

Comment: i think your mean is : `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo` @nkn

Comment: Might be, could you edit your question and add its contents?

Comment: contents added @nkn

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33900/discussion-between-meer-and-nkn).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason why it fails is because `yum` needs to know what the repo URL is. In your configuration file, you have this:

```
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/os/$basearch/
```

The `#` sign means it is commented, thus, `yum` will ignore that line and won't know which the URL is. Simply remove the hash sign and then use `yum` normally.

**Note**: You should remove it from *any* `baseurl` that you have commented, as the other repos are important as well.

Comment: all of repo? [update][base] and ...?? @nkn

Comment: Yes, if you don't want to use a repo, rather add the `enabled=0` option to them, but the `baseurl` should always be active.

Comment: Another error ... see edited question @nkn

Comment: Is It need any rebuild after editing this files??? @nkn

Comment: That looks like a DNS resolution error. Edit your `/etc/resolv.conf` file and add this line: `nameserver 8.8.8.8`, then try again.

Comment: I am using `vmware` and windows for hosting CentOS and my nameserver is IP of my host... Is it false ??Should I change this to the `8.8.8.8`? @nkn

Comment: The nameserver must be a host that performs `DNS` query resolution, so it shouldn't be your host unless you have a DNS server on it. The `8.8.8.8` is the Google's DNS server, which uses pretty much users. If you don't want to use it, you can ask your ISP for your DNS server hosts, but `8.8.8.8` should works as well.

Comment: Lost internet connection and can not renew IP with Cent-OS ... :( but thanks a lot my friend . @nkn